# Is it possible to select mapped entity into another mapped entity in a single query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there any elegant way to perform a nested LINQ selection into objects that are being selected themselves? In other words, let's assume there are three DB tables all with one-to-many relation: Schedule, Day (One schedule may have many days) and Activity (One day may have many activities. I would like to try to build a query which selects data into related mapped objects without the necessity of creating additional helper objects. Is that even possible? Please see below objects which map DB tables:

```
public Class Schedule{
   public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
   ...
   public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public List<Day> days; //Supposed to store Day objects
}

public Class Day{
   public int DayId { get; set; }
   ...
   public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public List<Activity> activities; //Supposed to store Activity objects
}

public Class Activity{
   public int ActivityId { get; set; }
   ...
   public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

At this point I use additional classes to fetch data: SchedulePrim, DaysPrim and ActivitiesPrim. After the query is executed I put Prims into [NotMapped] attributes of proper objects (see above) and then get rid of Prims. To me this seem like using unnecessary resources. The query looks somewhat like this:

```
from schedules in context.Schedules.Where(...)
select new SchedulePrim
{
    Schedule = schedules
    DaysPrim = from days in context.Days.Where(...)
               select new DaysPrim
               {
                    Day = days
                    ActivitiesPrim = from activities in context.Activities.Where(...)
                                     select new DaysPrim
                                     {
                                          Activity = activities
                                     }
               }
}
```

Here comes the logic of reprocessing fetched data into proper entities.
Is there a faster way to do this? The way that lets selecting data into [NotMapped] attributes on the fly, without the need of introducing additional processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just eliminate the NotMapped attributes and the "additional classes", make sure you have proper foreign keys, and load the data using Include.

```
db.Schedules.Include(s => s.Days).ThenInclude(d => d.Activities).Where(...)
```

Comment: It is what I needed indeed. However, wouldn't eliminating NotMapped cause issues when saving data back into DB?

Comment: EF is designed to work with navigation properties and entity graphs and subgraphs.  Using NotMapped is intended for unusual scenarios.

Comment: Apparently I have much to learn. I have tested your answer and it works like a charm. Thank you!